# How to disable the URL verification in TestComplete

Tags: url, automation, automated-tests, testcomplete

In this case, whenever I create a new record **Unique ID** is generated for each record and it is appended to the URL.

Whenever I execute the recorded TestComplete keyword test file, it creates a new record and it fails the execution. Because it compares with the old URL which was created in the recorded time and with the new URL which was executed in the run time.

**Look at the attachment**
[image: URL Difference]

How to handle this scenario in TestComplete.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you just need to replace the variable part of the link with the wildcard character for the object mapping criteria in the Name Mapping editor. Most probably, this will work until there are no other object links to the same FSDC object type at the same hierarchy level.

Make the URL value this: https://ap2.salesforce.com/00Q*